# Excel date formatting error

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm doing some work on an already done excel program, but I'm very rusty in this area or probably never had done something in this part, I'm very new in VBA so please don't judge me if it's a simple mistake or error the links are in the description.

So I have problem where if I put the confirmation option, for example: in one cell press "1" in the product you have, and in another cell write "S" if you already have the product and it puts you a date of today in another cell.

The problem is when I delete the info that I inserted, and reenter it the date deformats itself becoming smaller and the location on the cell changes too.

I'm going to put the links because, like I said I'm rusty and I can't find where the code of this date comes.

http://www.docdroid.net/12dh4/master-atual-20155.xls.html -->This one is the Excel

http://www.docdroid.net/12dhj/errorphotos.pdf.html --> photos showing error

this is the code of one of the sheets the other ones are almost the same, If you guys see the photos it would help to understand the error itself.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Range("v3:v500"), Target)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False

 On Error Resume Next


    If rng1.Value <> "" Then
        rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now()
    Else
        rng1.Offset(0, 2).Clear
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

---

Comment: You'd like us to fix code you're unwilling to locate?

Comment: Right click on the tab and choose "View code" then post it here (Edit your original message, don't put it in a comment)

Answer (score 0):

The code would be triggered when you do the changes at column V. You may find the code in the worksheet itself:
[image: worksheet code]

it will clear the date if the column V contains no value.

 By the way, the date is not getting smaller but it show the date of today in different format. you may check the date format by right click the cell and choose the format cells... option to look at it.